# Order by multiple columns with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some events like this

```
id----------title-----------date-------------status
1-----------birthday-------2018-03-12--------1
2-----------match----------2018-03-13--------2
3-----------anniversary----2018-03-10--------1
4-----------trip-----------2018-03-15--------1
5-----------birthday-------2018-03-17--------2
6-----------birthday-------2018-03-11--------1
```

Expected Result

```
id----------title-----------date-------------status
1-----------birthday-------2018-03-12--------1
4-----------trip-----------2018-03-15--------1
5-----------birthday-------2018-03-17--------2
2-----------match----------2018-03-13--------2
6-----------birthday-------2018-03-11--------1
3-----------anniversary----2018-03-10--------1
```

I need to query it like the first rows which have dates greater than today with status 1 should appear first and then the rest in desc.

Suppose today is 2018-03-11 then row with id 1 should appear first and then the rest of the rows is desc order

This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT *
FROM events
ORDER BY (date > CURDATE() and status = 1) asc,
         date desc
```

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data and also the expected result.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Added my attempts

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple keys in an `order by`:

```
order by (date >= curdate() and status = 1) desc,
         date desc
```

Comment: Tried it the same way but not working the way I am expecting ... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe your SQL should be something like this but is hard to say without expected results.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE 
  date > CURDATE()
AND
  status = 1
ORDER BY 
  date ASC
LIMIT 1

UNION 

SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE 
   id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      id
    FROM 
     [table]
    WHERE 
       date > CURDATE()
    AND
       status = 1
    LIMIT 1
   )
 AND
   date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY 
 date DESC
```

Comment: i've edited the query @Waqas to make sure the second part only selects dates greater then CURDATE()